# Как в c# узнать что все потоки завершились?

Tags: c#

Создаю max_threads потоков

```
for (int live_thread = 0; live_thread < max_threads; live_thread++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(поток);
    t.Start(live_thread);
}
```

Как узнать что все потоки завершились?

Comment: Может вам http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx подойдет? А так можно время от времени проверять IsAlive

Comment: system.threading.thread.threadstate

Answer (score 7):

У класса Thread есть свойства IsAlive и ThreadState, можете использовать их, чтобы узнать состояние потоков. Также можете написать какой-нибудь свой класс-обертку с соответствующим событием, хотя не уверен, что это лучший вариант. Кроме того можете вместо Thread использовать какой-нибудь BackgroundWorker. В нем можно задать соответствующий коллбэк Например:

```
for (int liveThread = 0; liveThread < maxThreads; liveThread++)
{
    int thread = liveThread;
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => { Thread.Sleep(thread * 500); Console.WriteLine(thread); };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("{0}nd thread is finished", thread);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать таким образом:

1. Объявить массив, в котором будут храниться все созданные Вами потоки.
2. Создать отдельный поток (это делать можно и в основном потоке), в котором в цикле периодически будет проверяться свойство IsAlive каждого потока, и в случае, когда все потоки уже завершили свою работу, будет вызван какой-либо метод.

Или же воспользоваться вариантом, предложенным @DreamChild.

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

1. Объявить массив и сохранить туда все потоки
2. Сделать проверку через функцию

```
private bool CheckThreadsForEnd(Thread[] aThreads /* Список потоков */)
        {
            foreach (Thread CurThread in aThreads)
            {
                if (!(CurThread.Join(TimeSpan.Zero)))
                {
                    return false;// хоть один не завершился
                }

            }
            return true;// все завершились
        }
```

Если в массиве может быть  0 потоков:

```
private bool CheckThreadsForEnd(Thread[] aThreads /* Список потоков */)
        {
            if (aThreads.Length == 0) { return true;/* 0 потоков*/}

            foreach (Thread CurThread in aThreads)
            {
                if(CurThread == null)
                {
                    return true;/*пусто*/
                }
                if (!(CurThread.Join(TimeSpan.Zero)))
                {
                    return false;// хоть один не завершился
                }

            }
            return true;// все завершились
        }
```